# Using xdrip-js in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Has anyone experience with the whole process of implementing Xdrip-js. (https://github.com/xdrip-js/xdrip-js) into the Ionic application (Ionic 3,Ionic 4).